# How do I use sweetalert2 with php form in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter, sweetalert2

Details: How do I use sweetalert2 with PHP form in CodeIgniter? 
Actually, I want to show sweetalert2 on submitting PHP form and then show sweetalert2 to confirm data, if the user confirms data should be submitted and then redirect to next page.

Problem: But in my case, it directly redirects to next page without my pressing confirm button on sweetalert.

PHP:

```
echo form_open( '/redirect to',['onsubmit'=>'return submitForm(this);']);
```

JavaScript:

```
function submitForm(){

    swal({ 

    title: "Are you Sure!",

     text: "Data is Correct?",

           type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#cc3f44",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes!",
            closeOnConfirm: false
        }).then(okay =>  {
            if(okay)
            {
              alert("check");
            }
            else
            { 
              alert("not sure");
            }
        });

}
```

PHP

```
echo form_submit(['name'=>'submit','id'=>'submit','value'=>'Submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary btn_size' ]);
```

Please help me regarding this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: what does it showing right now

Comment: it just redirect to next page without my confirmation

Answer (score 1):

### I am posting my working code here.I deleted event by sweet alert It was mapped on button by giving a class name 'demo' to button hope it will help

```
$('.demo').click(function () {
    //e.preventDefault();
    var id= document.getElementById('id').value;
    swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Your will not be able to recover this Event!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plz!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                    location.href='<?php echo site_url('calendarController/delete_Event/'); ?>'+'/'+id;

            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "Your event is safe :)", "error");
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: If you still feel any complexity you can ask!

Comment: also make sure your library is included in a right way

Comment: that's the library i included in my js <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.10.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

Comment: post your model and view here lets see what we can do